# read csv and add to parameters class python

Tags: python

i have a problem when reading csv and add to parameters the class
and use function check "This check if there are car or no " is not work for all data what i read 
for example 
if I write "Corolla" or "sunny" is told me There are no car and is it in the file but if write the Sonata the function is work I do not know why is the last sentence is work just

this the file

```
Nissan sunny 2012
Toyota Corolla 2010
Hyundai Sonata 2013
```

The code

class Car

```
class car():
    def __init__(self , company_name , name_of_car , model)
        self.company_name = company_name
        self.name_of_car = name_of_car
        self.model = mode

    def check (self , name):
        if name in self.name_of_car:
            print("there are car")
        else:
            print("There are no car")

    def list (self):
        listt =  'The name of company '+self.company_name + ' the car is '+ self.name_of_car + ' The model is ' +self.model )
        return listt.title()
```

class test

```
import csv
import Car
with open( "/Users/saleh/Desktop/carss.csv", 'r') as file:
    x = csv.reader(file)
for i in x :
    c = Car.car(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4])
    print(c.list())
    print(c.check('Sonata'))
```

The output for Corolla is

> There are no car

The output for Sonata is

> there are car

Comment: You're checking each car in the list, and saying whether it's Sonata.

Comment: You're not searching the whole list for Sonata.

Comment: i want to check for all the car

Comment: how can i check

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want. Can it be this one: change `print(c.check('Sonata'))` to `print(c.check(i[1]))`. Also why do you have 5 parameters in your instances, I.e. `i[1]...i[5]`?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? As an aside, naming a function `list` is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `check()` function so it returns a boolean rather than printing.

```
    def check (self, name):
        return name in self.name_of_car
```

Make a list of all the `car` objects. Then use `any()` to check if any of them are Sonata.

```
all_cars = [Car.car(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4]) for i in x]
if any(c.check('Sonata') for c in all_cars):
    print("There are car")
else:
    print("There are no car")
```